# is there a moduli of stable infinity categories?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, infinity-categories

I know there exists a groupoid-valued prestack parameterizing (connected) triangulated dg-categories (ie the points of this moduli are *not* objects of a fixed dg-category, but rather dg-categories themselves).

Has anything been done for stable $\infty$-categories?

[Connectedness is a condition on Hochschild cohomology: $HH^{<0}=0$ and $HH^0=k$.]

Comment: Rathen than answering, I'm interested in what you know :) What is a connected triangulated dg-category and where can I find references about their moduli stack?

Comment: Exactly what you mean "parametrizing stable $\infty$-categories"? Usually you get prestacks when your type of objects depend on a parameter. Do you mean $R$-enriched stable categories (where $R$ varies in rings)?

Comment: If you just want a prestack, rather than say a geometric stack, I don't see the relevance of connectedness or of the dg vs stable distinction...

Comment: ie for any Connective E_oo ring spectrum R you have the groupoid of R-linear stable oo-cats (ie R-mod module categories), thats the prestack

Comment: (unless by groupoid you mean 1-groupoid rather than oo-groupoid? Though connectedness still seems not quite right for that- you'd want a t-structure maybe? Connectedness is relevant for geometric properties, like deformation theory)

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi I mean the prestack which associates to any (derived) ring R some (appropriately set-theoretically sorted) $\infty$-groupoid of R-linear stable categories. I would like to know if the infinitesimal theory of this has been settled (I cannot find a definitive answer in the literature, but only "approximations" of what one would actually want).

Comment: @DenisNardin apparently MO lets you notify only one user at a time. So, there, you've been notified.

Comment: You would need good geometric properties to settle the infinitesimal part. As far as I know, this is rather open. I know some advances are being made with respect to deformations.

Comment: @pro, would you mind explaining what you mean by infinitesimal theory here?

Comment: @AdeelKhan I would like to know what the tangent space looks like, ie if F is the prestack (say we work over some ring k), can we describe $F(k[\epsilon])$? Is this in the literature? Even for k a field would be nice.

Comment: @AdeelKhan I must've confused myself regarding connectedness. The reference I had in mind is a D-stack $Cat^{CW}_{[n,0]}$ buried somewhere in Toen-Vezzosi's HAGII. Though I remember they comment on the fact that this is not very useful in the algebro-geometric context, as in general D(X) for a smooth and projective variety X will not be a point of it (something to do with the boundedness condition [n,0], I don't remember the details, sorry!).

Comment: @pro, thanks.  I know that moduli stacks of dg-categories are discussed in To\"en's beautiful paper on derived Azumaya algebras, which has been generalized to a spectral stack parametrizing R-linear categories for R a commutative ring spectrum by Antieau-Gepner.  I don't think they discuss the type of issue you are interested in there, though.

Comment: @AdeelKhan thanks for the reference, I'll have a look.